# MySQL: Don't select records matched in other join

Tags: mysql, sql

Maybe my title is wrong but I want to show you my query and what's the error I have in my result to perform a search:

**Query**

```
select distinct
    U.id,
    U.first_name,
    U.last_name,
    C.from_user,
    case when C.to_user is null 
        then 99
        else C.to_user
    end as to_user,
   case when C.status is null 
        then 99
        else C.status
    end as connection_type,
    case when C2.from_user is null 
        then 99
        else C2.from_user
    end as from_user_2,
    C2.to_user as to_user_2,
    case when C2.status is null 
        then 99
        else C2.status
    end as connection_type_2,
    ( 3959 * acos(
        cos(radians(19.3901580))
        * cos(radians(L.latitude))
                * cos(radians(L.longitude) - radians(-99.1733260))
                + sin(radians(19.3901580))
                * sin(radians(L.latitude)))
    ) AS distance
from users U
left join connections C on C.from_user = U.id
left join connections C2 on C2.to_user = U.id
left join locations L on L.user_id = U.id
where U.id != 10
#group by U.id
having distance < 70
    #and (connection_type_2 = 1 or connection_type_2 = 99)
   #and from_user_2 != 10
   #and (to_user != 10 or connection_type != 3)
   #and to_user != 10
order by distance asc
```

**Result**

[image]

If I uncomment the lines commented in the query, this is the result

[image]

**user id: 10**

If the **to_user = 10** and with the **from_user id** the **connection_type = 3** I need to don't get the user which already matches with this kind of condition and that means, the user which have the id **30** won't be selected.

So I have that issue, are many rules for this search function of course but this is the last step to get it done!

**EDIT:**

**A bit explanation of the requests**

- A users connected is when the status between them is 3
- A incoming request is when the status between them is 1 like:

  - from_user:20 to_user:10 status:1 (the user 10 has a incoming request from 20
  - from_user:10 to_user:20 status:1 (the user 20 has a incoming request from 10
- A outgoing request is when the status between them is 1 like:

  - from_user:20 to_user:10 status:1 (the user 10 has sent a request to 20
  - from_user:10 to_user:20 status:1 (the user 20 has sent a request to 10
- A blocked user is when the status from_user to_user is 2:

  - from_user:20 to_user:30 status:2 (the user 20 blocked the user 30)

**Rules**

Get:

- I need to get the users which doesn't have any requests, it means users which are not in the connections table
- Get the users which has sent to the current user (10 in this case) a request.

Don't get:

- Don't get users which I already sent an invitation to them
- Don't get users blocked

Hope you can help me!

Comment: your criteria is a bit complicated. can you make it clear?

Comment: @Tim3880 I know, there are like 5 rules for that query let me try to explain them in the post.

Comment: @Tim3880 Check my post edited please

Comment: your criteria is still far from clear . Don't get users blocked (by whom? any or #10?); Don't get users which I (who is I ? #10) already sent an invitation to them. users which are not in the connections table AND sent to the current user (10 in this case) a request, how? the user 20 blocked the user 30 (#20 is the sender, why #30 is blocked?)

Comment: I set #10 as an example because is the current user id logged in the app which is trying to search users. --- I is the #10 (the example id) --- all the posibilities are in the explanation on the requests... Is very hard to be clear since the query in fact is difficult. --- #30 is blocked because #20 has block  this #30 id

Comment: I can understand that but it's still not clear enough. you can rewrite your statement using IN and NOT IN, to make things clear and optimize it later once you get the correct result.

Comment: @Tim3880 I understand, don't worry even is difficult to me explain all the details about the problem or the logic of the search function.

Comment: If you want, we can start a chat so i can get my questions answered first.

Comment: Sure why not, hope you can help to fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81332/discussion-between-soldiercorp-and-tim3880).

Comment: And what do you actually want to select: requests or users? You say you want users that ... and don't ..., but your results contain connections. Dont mix DISTINCT and GROUP BY by the way, and when you GROUP BY then use it with aggregations (SUM, COUNT, etc.). Then your case clauses can be replaced with COALESCE for readability, e.g. `coalesce(c.to_user ,99) as to_user`. Well, I guess you can sort this all out with Tim3880's help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
select * from (
   select id, first_name, last_name, (select  3959 * acos(
        cos(radians(19.3901580))
        * cos(radians(L.latitude))
                * cos(radians(L.longitude) - radians(-99.1733260))
                + sin(radians(19.3901580))
                * sin(radians(L.latitude)))
                from locations l where l.userid = u.id ) as distance  from  users u
  where 
  (
   id in (select from_user from connections where to_user=10 and status=1)
    or (id not in (select from_user from connections where to_user=10) and id not in (select to_user from connections where from_user=10) )
  ) 
  and id !=10
  and id not in (select to_user from connections where from_user =10 and status=2)
  and id not in (select to_user from connections where from_user=10 and status=1) 
  and id not in (select to_user from connections where from_user=10 and status=3)
  and id not in (select from_user from connections where to_user=10 and status=3)
) a
where distance < 10;
```

It's not optimized yet but you need get the correct results first.

To add the status of connections with the current user

```
select *,
   (select status from connections l where (l.to_user=a.id
          and l.from_user = 10
            or l.from_user = a.id  and l.to_user=10 
     limit 1)  as status
  from (
   select id, first_name, last_name, (select  3959 * acos(
        cos(radians(19.3901580))
        * cos(radians(L.latitude))
                * cos(radians(L.longitude) - radians(-99.1733260))
                + sin(radians(19.3901580))
                * sin(radians(L.latitude)))
                from locations l where l.userid = u.id ) as distance  from  users u
  where 
  (
   id in (select from_user from connections where to_user=10 and status=1)
    or (id not in (select from_user from connections where to_user=10) and id not in (select to_user from connections where from_user=10) )
  ) 
  and id !=10
  and id not in (select to_user from connections where from_user =10 and status in (1,2,3)) 
  and id not in (select from_user from connections where to_user=10 and status=3)
) a
where distance < 10
```

Comment: Those three first not in can be converted to only one `and id not in (select to_user from connections where from_user =10 and status in(1,2,3))`

Comment: @JorgeCampos That's true!

Comment: Hi, could you help me to select the "status" field from the connections table please.

Comment: you can join the result of above query and your connection table to include the status. The actual key depends on which status you need.

Comment: Using a join I have to join twice to the table connections to "from_user" and "to_user" and I want to get the "status" only for the users who are in the connections table for the current user (10) and if not well show null. And using join I have the same issue as my original post, is returning more rows with the same user but connected with other users not with the current (10)

Comment: So, I think I have to get the status field in the wherein because joining the tables will be necessary to compare again the conditions.

Comment: Hope you can help me guys, this is the last step with this query @JorgeCampos

Comment: I didn't test the new code so please adjust it if there is any syntax or logical issues.

Comment: Sure, let me test.. by the way one parenthesis is missing I shall to put here or l.from_user = a.id  and l.to_user=10) ? /// I added that parenthesis there and apparently is working, let me perform a full test in the app.

Comment: Your last piece of code worked like a charm, thanks again!